# Как расширить функционал класса SimpleAdapter на андроид?

Tags: android, listview, java

Как у класса SimpleAdapter расширить функционал, так чтобы в новом классе наследуюшемся от SimpleAdapter была одна обработка нажатий на итемы, и в зависимости от нажатого итема переклюячаться между активити? Суть в том что этот листвью может вызываться в любой активити(это боковое меню), и хотелось бы в одном месте прописать Все переходы по нажатию на итем листвью.

Предполагаю делать это так:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    Class<?> ct[] = {Main.class, Second.class,Next_1.class,Next_2.class};

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ct[position]);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Создаем в статической переменной массив из `Activity.class` всех активите, которые нужно будет открывать.  
И при клике на итемы достаем из этого массива класс активити, который лежит по индексу нажатого элемента(position), что бы передать его в интент...  
На сколько я понял - вы хотите насоздавать на каждом layout по такому listView что бы везде было это меню?  
Если да, то это не правильный подход. Правильный - создать 1 layout с этим меню, и контейнером под остальное пустое месть, и менять содержимое этого пустого места на нужную страницу. Это реализовывается при помощи фрагментов(Fragment)

Comment: А зачем Вы мне рассказываете то что написанно в коде выше? И кстати я это уже реализовал без фрагментов!

Comment: Расскажите, как реализовали без фрагментов?